# POST parameter is null in when it's a hand made type

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dto, edmx

I have a asp.net 4.5.2 web api and one POST method receive a DTO parameter I've coded by hand like these:

```
using System;

namespace WebApi.Models.DTO
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyModelDto
    {
        public MyModelDto()
        {

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I call this method from Postman the parameter is always null, but if I design the same DTO class in EntityFramewok (edmx model) and use it as parameter I could receive the data inside the post method as it was send.
I could not realize what I'm missing in my hand made class?
Why it works using EF and not with my class?
Setting the parameter as dynamic also works...

```
[HttpPost]
[JwtAuthentication]
[Route("api/bills/invoice")]
public JsonResult<WebApi.Models.DTO.MyModelDto> Post(WebApi.Models.DTO.MyModelDto param)
{
    // Here param is always NULL
}

[HttpPost]
[JwtAuthentication]
[Route("api/bills/invoice")]
public JsonResult<Data.MyModelDto> Post(Data.MyModelDto param)
{
    // Here param wors! based on the EF class
}
public JsonResult<Data.MyModelDto> Post(dynamic param)
{
    // Here param wors! using dynamic data type
}
```

Comment: It should work either way, the POST really does not have anything to do with the model. When you are sending the parameter from Postman how are you doing that? Just a guess but maybe the model is being serialized differently: uppercase vs camel case.

Comment: The example you gave should work. You might need to paste the exact DTO object that is not working. The #null value will be when the model binder cannot implicitly convert the JS object to the Post parameter. AFAIK the binder is case insensitive but double-check the naming of your DTO properties. Sometimes typos slip in.

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you send the data via Postman.

I don't have Postman here to test but make sure you select Json Type when sending data and then your sent data needs to match your DTO. Something like:

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "Type":"whatever",
   "Code":"whatever"
}
```

This data goes in the body of the request since you are sending a Post request.

One extra observation, your DTO does not need an empty constructor, you can get rid of it. There is nothing wrong with:

```
public class MyModelDto
    {       
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }
```

For testing purposes get rid of your Jwt authentication, until you get the calls running correctly